# Getting the function's result from a object in javascript using a loop

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a little problem.

I have this constructor:

```
function person(vName, vLastname, vID) {
    var name= vName;
    var lastname = vLastname;
    var id= vID;

    this.getName = function () {
        return name;
    }

    this.getLast = function () {
        return lastname;
    }

    this.getId = function () {
        return id;
    }

    this.getJSON = function () {
        var json = {"name": name, "last": lastname, "id": id};
        return JSON.stringify(json);
    };
}
```

I create an object:

```
var person = new person("John", "Connor", "t3000");
```

and I want to show his info using a loop like:

```
for (index in person) {
    document.getElementById("dPerson").innerHTML += "<br>"+index+" : " + person[index]+"</br>";
}
```

But what I get is just something like:

```
getName : function () { return name; }

getLast : function () { return lastname; }

getId : function () { return id; }

getJSON : function () { var json = {"name": name, "last": lastname, "id": id}; return JSON.stringify(json); }
```

What can I do? I dont want to make public the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. The only thing you need to do is to call the function in stead of getting the function definition.

Like this:

```
        for (index in person){
            document.getElementById("dPerson").innerHTML += "" + index + 
                " : " + person[index]() + "";
        }
```